# Update SQL data, consolidating columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by

My table looks like this:

```
Name | Maths | Science | Social
-----+-------+---------+-------    
ABC    NULL      A+      NULL
ABC     B       NULL     NULL 
ABC    NULL     NULL      A
XYZ     A       NULL     NULL
XYZ    NULL      B       NULL
```

The situation is grades are given by each teacher and are stored in a table in the above format. Student ABC has attended all the papers and has grades for his performance and student XYZ appeared only maths and science so he should be having only TWO grades

Now my result should look like

```
Name | Maths | Science | Social
-----+-------+---------+-------    
ABC     B        A+        A
XYZ     A        B        NULL
```

I am trying to retrieve this with all the possible options I am having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you apply `MAX` then `NULL` values will be ignored and the desired value will be returned for each subject:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Maths), MAX(Science), MAX(Social)
FROM Grades
GROUP BY Name
```